# get data back from dynamic number of ajax calls with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic number of ajax calls I need to make where I use promises that looks like:

```
  saveNewProjects(projects) {
    var projectPromises: any[] = [];

    for (var projectName in projects) {
        var project = projects[projectName][0].Project;
        if (project && project.id == 0 && project.name !== null) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            (function(deferred) {
                        $.ajax({
                        url: "projects",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(project),
                        crossDomain: $.support.cors,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: $.support.cors,
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        },
                    });
                    projectPromises.push(deferred);
                })(deferred);
        }
    }
    return $.when.apply($, projectPromises).promise();
}

  this.saveNewProjects(bioSamplesByProject).then(() => {
            console.log("i'm done");
            console.log(arguments);
```

But arguments is an empty array.  How do I get the data for each promise so I can have success and failure callbacks for each individual one and also do something when all the ajax calls are done?

Comment: FYI: $.ajax returns a promise !

Comment: do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J92Kj/)?